# Get .NET Remoting XML SOAP message at client application before deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

The error below only occurred when client computer is using certain network wifi connection:
[image: Deserialization error]

I suspect that something in the network (perhaps the router) is altering the content (like returning some network error message), so the received content does not match the XML format when .NET remoting client tries to deserialize it.

Is there a way to retrieve the XML content before deserialization process, so I can inspect what causes the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Few questions: 1) how do you know it is network? 2) have you checked buffer/encoding-style policy in server-side & Client SIde?

Comment: 1)The error occurred only on one wifi connection, so when the connection changed to other wifi/mobile hotspot, it's no problem. 2) Is the encoding means like unicode/ANSI thing? How can I check it? Thanks for replying!

Comment: 2) yes there ways to configure message encoding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/message-encoding. It needs to be same for client and wcf service for it to work

Comment: See answer below, it is very helpful in finding issues like this :)

Answer (score 0):

TO your actual question:

> Is there a way to retrieve the XML content before deserialization process, so I can inspect what causes the error?

yes, you can configure WCF diagnostic logging: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/configuring-message-logging

Thanks

Comment: The suggestion is for WCF, can it be used for .NET remoting too?

Comment: Also, how to use it at client side? Thank in advance!